# Fill/Padding space between 2 Labels with dots in GridPane (JavaFX)

Tags: css, javafx, label, padding, gridpane

### Starting point:

- GridPane with 2 Columns
- each Column has a Label

[image]

---

### Like-to-have output:

- space between the labels filled by dots

[image]

So far I have only come across String solutions in which the target length of the combined String is known. But this case doesn't do it for me because I need a solution which can also works when screen size changes and therefore the space between Labels do change dynamically. Could you guys please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You could put the 2 `Label`s in a `HBox` with a `Region` in between them, set `hgrow` for the labels and the `Region` to `NEVER` and `ALWAYS` respectively and use a linear gradient as background for the region that draws half of it's size black and the other half transparent.

#### Example

```
// 20 px wide horizontal gradient alternating between black and transparent with immediate color switch
private static final Paint FILL = new LinearGradient(
        0, 0,
        10, 0,
        false,
        CycleMethod.REPEAT,
        new Stop(0, Color.BLACK),
        new Stop(0.5, Color.BLACK),
        new Stop(0.5, Color.TRANSPARENT)
);

// create background for regions
private static final Background BACKGROUND = new Background(new BackgroundFill(FILL, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY));

private static void addRow(Pane parent, String s1, String s2) {
    // create labels
    Label label1 = new Label(s2);
    Label label2 = new Label('['+s2+']');
    
    // create filler region with "stroke width" 2
    Region filler = new Region();
    filler.setPrefHeight(2);
    filler.setBackground(BACKGROUND);
    
    HBox hbox = new HBox(5, label1, filler, label2);
    hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    HBox.setHgrow(label1, Priority.NEVER);
    HBox.setHgrow(label2, Priority.NEVER);
    HBox.setHgrow(filler, Priority.ALWAYS);
    hbox.setFillHeight(false);
    
    parent.getChildren().add(hbox);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    VBox root = new VBox();
    addRow(root, "JBoss", "DOWN");
    addRow(root, "GlassFish", "UP");
    addRow(root, "verylongprocessname", "UP");

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

---

You could also use a border (top only) on the `Region` instead of using a background and do not set `prefHeight`. This would allow you to actually use dots instead of strokes, but since your picture shows strokes, I posted the background approach instead...

Comment: Your approach is out of the ordinary. I will try it and report back tomorrow. Once again, Fabian you are just like a Java God!